# Error within Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

```
<cffunction name="getBackgrounds" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="dsn" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="page" type="string" required="false" />
    <cfset var getBackground="" />
    <cfquery name="getBackground" datasource="#arguments.dsn#">
     SELECT page_id , photo 
     FROM page_photos 
     WHERE page_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Trim( arguments.page )#" />
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn getBackground>
</cffunction>
```

---

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.supersized({
        slide_interval: 6000,
        transition: 1,
        transition_speed: 1000,
        slide_links: 'false',
        slides: [ < cfoutput query = "getBackground" > {
                image: '#getBackground.photo#'
            } < cfif getBackground.CurrentRow lt getBackground.RecordCount > , < /cfif> 
               </cfoutput >
        ]

    });
});
```

But I get an error . I tried something similar before and it was working, but I can't find that example back. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you get ?

Comment: how about formatting your code so we can all read it

Comment: As per @Sanjeev: don't simply say "I get an error", you need to *tell us what the error is*.

Comment: ColdFusion Error? JavaScript Error? Is there really a space before <cfoutput ?

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention the error...what does it say?  Can 
you include the generated javascript?

Also, another way to populate the array would be like 
so:

```
<script>
 var arr = [];
 <cfoutput query="getBackground">
  var img = {};
 img.image = '#getBackground.photo#';
 arr.push(img);
 </cfoutput> 
  </script>
```